# Is it possible to force intel integrated graphics to not resample 1920 on a 4k monitor?

Tags: gpu, resolution, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics, 4k-resolution

I bought a 4k monitor to share between my work laptop and my gaming machine. On the gaming machine, 4k looks stunning, but on my laptop, the best the integrated GPU can put out is 1920p, which is fine. What I don't understand is why it is resampling the output. The display output I have it set to is 1920x1080. The monitor's native resolution is 3840x2160, which is twice the width and twice the height.

I would figure that the iGPU would just double the pixel dimensions, but instead it resamples, causing the pixels to be interpolated and blurred.

Is there any way to force or configure the integrated GPU to prevent it from resampling when doubling the pixel dimensions/increasing them by a base of 2?

Comment: If the iGPU is only able to output 1080 then it is only going to put out 1080 because it literally does not have the bandwidth to run at 4K. I'd suspect the scaling is actually happening in the panel itself if your laptop cannot output a 4K signal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. What I am looking for I believe is called integer scaling, which is based on nearest neighbor scaling.

Intel apparently did not implement either until 2019 according to [their article on the feature](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/integer-scaling-support-on-intel-graphics.html).

You need an 11th gen Intel CPU, and you can enable either from the graphics control center.

Answer (score 0):

Since most displays only perform bilinear scaling, your best option for a sharp image is to disable image scaling in the monitor's OSD. The option may be described as 1:1 or native scaling.

Since your IGP is only capable of outputting 1080p or lower, the IGP isn't performing the scaling, so it's relevant if the IGP supports integer scaling. It's actually the display performing the scaling.